# Why NSTimer sends positions every 5 seconds instead of every 60?

Tags: objective-c, time, nstimer

Why NSTimer sends positions every 5 seconds instead of every 60?

```
- (void)startTimer {
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(sendPosition)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
}

- (void)stopTimer {
    if(self.timer){
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: That code in `startTimer` certainly will cause sendPosition to fire every 60s.  But, if you call startTimer twice, it can start two timers.  (It may also be leaking the first timer).

Comment: show us who is calling startTimer.

Comment: It looks like the reasonable answer given doesn't solve the problem.  I think everyone who wants to help with this will be stuck unless you add some more information to the question.  Can you show more about the caller to startTimer? Can you add NSLog to the startTimer and paste the console output here?  Otherwise, I'll vote to close this question as lacking sufficient debug info.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that there are multiple timers created due to multiple firing of startTimer function. To ensure that there is only one instance of such timer, you can implement the following.

```
- (void)startTimer {

// stop and remove timer first if it is already there
   if(self.timer){
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
    }

self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(sendPosition)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
}
```

This way, no matter how many times the startTimer was called,there is only one instance of it.

Comment: This is a great answer, but a very common mistake is to have multiple instances of the object that contains `startTimer`. This won't protect against that mistake (because each instance has its own `self.timer`). The OP should make sure both that they are only calling `startTimer` once, and that there is only one instance of this class.

Comment: Show us who is self? And is there any chance that you may have created multiple instance of self?